# Classification report for Object Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, object-detection

I am working on Object Detection. I know the standard to check how good you model is to calculate the `mAP` but I want to take it one step further. I want to generate a classification report for each class. For this I want to count `TP`, `FP` and `FN`. I want to avoid loops here and finding a quick way to calculate this. In a nutshell, the steps include:

1) Discard all the predicted boxes where the confidence score < 0.6
2) Compute IOU of the remaining boxes with GT. This is `vectorized`
3) For all the boxes, that have an IOU >= 0.5, check the corresponding `predicted` and `ground-truth` labels. 
4) Update `TP`, `FP` and `FN` count

Here is an example:

```
Ground-Truth:
[[142. 208. 158. 346.]  person,  
 [ 39.  63. 203. 112.]  dog,     
 [ 49.  75. 203. 125.]  person,
 [ 31.  69. 201. 125.]  dog,
 [ 50.  72. 197. 121.]  cat,
 [ 35.  51. 196. 110.]  dog]]


Predictions:

[[243. 203. 348. 279.]  cat     0.7,
 [ 54.  66. 198. 114.]  person  0.5,
 [ 42.  78. 186. 126.]  person  0.5,
 [ 18.  63. 235. 135.]  person  0.5,
 [ 54.  72. 198. 120.]  person  0.5]
```

I calculate IOU in a `vectorized` way and get this array:

```
IOU:

array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.79577124, 0.48706725, 0.51433694, 0.62690467],
       [0.        , 0.6242775 , 0.787838  , 0.49283153, 0.79685193],
       [0.        , 0.65112543, 0.70033115, 0.609319  , 0.72605044],
       [0.        , 0.7406585 , 0.70739084, 0.4610215 , 0.94662803],
       [0.        , 0.6147791 , 0.39040923, 0.43102074, 0.48987743]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Now I am unable to figure out how to match class labels in a faster way, given that this IOUs matrix. Can anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your IOU metric output correctly (each row represent a bounding box prediction and each column a bounding box for each object in the image). 
 Then you can get for each row the index of the column that maximizes IOU metric:

```py
indices = np.argmax(IOU, axis=1)
```

With those indices, access to your `ground-truth` labels.